# django test / python syntax

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm new Django and also to modern web-development . i had a doubt the testing of app.
The confusion may be because of my less python knowledge . I was a Java programmer so i got a doubt with the code below. Here's my code:

```
def test_was_published_recently_with_old_poll(self):
    """
    was_published_recently() should return False for polls whose pub_date
    is older than 1 day
    """
    old_poll = Poll(pub_date=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))
    self.assertEqual(old_poll.was_published_recently(), False)
```

This my code in test.py of my app. What's actually happening at `Poll(pub_date=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))`...
    My question is (Poll is a class defined in models.py) what's actually happening here?
    Can anyone please explain in details ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At '$' Poll(pub_date=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)) you create a class with field pub_date set to timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30).

For example, now is 2012-07-31 11:19:42.897000+00:00. The Poll constructor will create class with pub_date set to 2012-07-01 11:19:42.897000+00:00

Answer (score 1):

Since you say your experience is in Java, I have no idea why you are having a problem here. This syntax is almost exactly the same as Java's: you create a `Poll` instance whose `pub_date` field is set to a certain value, ie the date as of 30 days ago.

Comment: My thought when he mentioned Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unit test that's making sure the `was_published_recently` method of the `Poll` object is working as expected. It creates an instance of `Poll`, passing it a `datetime` 30 days in the past… and because this wasn't ‘*recent*’ calling the `was_published_recently` method is expected to return False. You're then using `self.assertEqual()` to test for the expected behaviour.